# How can I set the text and color of the event target in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, html-table, meteor-blaze

I am loading an array of items in a Meteor template like so:

```
{{#each person}}
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="sendtextckbx" checked></td>
    <td>{{per_firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{per_lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{per_streetaddr1}}</td>
    <td>{{per_streetaddr2}}</td>
    <td>{{per_placename}}</td>
    <td>{{per_stateorprov}}</td>
    <td>{{per_zipcode}}</td>
    <td>{{per_emailaddr}}</td>
    <td class="textnum">{{per_phone}}</td>
    <td class="textmorph">Not sent</td>
    <td>{{per_notes}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

I want to update the td with the id "textmorph" when it is clicked. It starts off containing the text "Not sent" but when the td is clicked, I want it to cycle through other text strings, and change color accordingly, too.

Since there are 1..N instances of this td, I can't just assign to it via the class value, as there will be many sharing the same class (one for each person).

I think I can get the current value via evt.target.value, but I don't know how to set the value. This is my "pseudocode" (also known as a wild guess):

```
Template.peopleGrid.events({
  'click #btnTextChecked': function() {
    alert('you clicked the btnTextChecked button');
  },
  'click #textmorph': function(evt) {
    var currentText = evt.target.value;
    alert(currentText);
    if (currentText === 'Not sent') {
      evt.target.value = 'Sent';
      evt.target.color = amber;
    }
    else if (currentText === 'Sent') {
      evt.target.value = 'Need Help';
      evt.target.color = red;
    }
    else if (currentText === 'Not sent') {
      evt.target.value = 'Are OK';
      evt.target.color = green;
    }
  }
});
```

...but I'm not confident it's even close to being what it should be. In fact, when I test it out, ~

So how can I act on the selected tds, changing the text and the color? The app runs with the code above, but gives me an "undefined" alert when I click the "Not sent" tds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not too far. In pure javascript, you actually get and set an element's content through its [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property. As for the color, you set it through [`style.color`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp). And use quotes around color names!

Therefore:

```
Template.peopleGrid.events({
  'click #btnTextChecked': function() {
    alert('you clicked the btnTextChecked button');
  },
  'click #textmorph': function(evt) {
    var clicked = evt.target;
    var currentText = clicked.innerHTML;
    alert(currentText);
    if (currentText === 'Not sent') {
      clicked.innerHTML = 'Sent';
      clicked.style.color = 'amber';
    }
    else if (currentText === 'Sent') {
      clicked.innerHTML = 'Need Help';
      clicked.style.color = 'red';
    }
    else if (currentText === 'Need Help') {
      clicked.innerHTML = 'Are OK';
      clicked.style.color = 'green';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll czech it out tonight.