# Where is the unexpected token here (Meteor)?

Tags: javascript, meteor, innerhtml, meteor-blaze

With the following code:

```
Template.peopleGrid.events({
  'click #btnTextChecked': function() {
    alert('you clicked the btnTextChecked button');
  },
  'click #textmorph': function(evt) {
    var clicked = evt.target;
    var currentText = clicked.innerHTML;
    alert(currentText);
    if (currentText === 'Not sent') {
      clicked.innerHTML = 'Sent';
      clicked.style.color = 'yellow';
    } else if (currentText === 'Sent') {
      clicked.innerHTML = 'Need Help';
      clicked.style.color = 'red';
    } else if (currentText === 'Need Help') {
      clicked.innerHTML = 'Are OK';
      clicked.style.color = 'green';
    }
  }
});
```

I'm getting this:

```
   While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
   client/ruokclient.js:56: client/ruokclient.js: Unexpected token (56:0)

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Yet there is no line 56. The code above goes through line 55, and that's where ruokclient.js ends.

So what could be causing this?

The code I'm using is from the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226835/how-can-i-set-the-text-and-color-of-the-event-target-in-meteor).

Comment: If the code ends at line 55 and it complains about the first character of line 56 then the unexpected token is probably the end of file. Check if you have any brace unclosed.

Comment: It seems okay at first glance. Could you try reproducing it on http://meteorpad.com/ ?

Comment: @slebetman: Yeah, that was it; in this simple app, my "isClient" block was missing its final "}"
Somebody snuck in and deleted it, apparently, while I wasn't looking (that's my story, and...)

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: If you don't mind, I'll add my comment as an answer because the error message is not specific to your project and isn't obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is one of those cases where the error message of the interpreter/compiler isn't helpful. Reading between the lines, if the code ends at line 55 and it complains about the first character of line 56 then the unexpected token is probably the end of file.

Check if you have any brace unclosed.